# ERB checkboxes with different id but same value acting weirdly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web, erb

For my ERB, if there are checkboxes with same values but for different forms, after a new render due to create error the checkboxes for different forms with same value gets checked. It doesn't seem to matter their different ids.

I have several checkboxes for model Option with two columns :size and :color. Currently, I'm using a bigger model to accept_nested_attributes for the Option model.

In my form, for each Option, I'm putting a checkbox with hidden value for color and checkbox for size such that:

```
<%= form_for @big do |big| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :options do |option| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :color, value: "Red" %>
        <%= f.check_box :size, {}, "Small", nil %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :options do |option| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :color, value: "Blue" %>
        <%= f.check_box :size, {}, "Small", nil %>
    <% end %>

    .....

<% end %>
```

The options above have each unique ids according to html and everything but just gets checked equally, which I suspect is due to the same value.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. 
This was more deeply rooted into my shabby controller practice mixed with overusing ERB fields_for.

So for my controller, I only have one @bigmodel.options.build, and in the controller I have four f.fields_for option. The problem was that the big model had one association to the options and therefore all options were being treated equally, regardless of the html output.

Since the html output was unique, the value submission was okay - not buggy - but when something failed server side, there were myriad of problems bound to come out to html.